# The Azure region us south central us does not show up when creating a cosmosdb account

Tags: azure, mongodb

[image: dropdown screenshot]

[image: dropdown screenshot]

[image]

As you can see in the screenshots, the region I need does **not** show up in the dropdown and I cannot select the us south central region (in Texas). The resource group is in Texas tho, and I have some VMs running there.

According to [Azure Products by Region | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?regions=non-regional,us-south-central&products=cosmos-db) cosmos db IS available in south central us.

IDK if this is a bug in the portal.

Answer (score 1):

If the region does not appear it is because it is capacity constrained. You can raise a support ticket and ask if they can white list your subscription. In some cases this is possible.

Comment: Hello. Do I need to hire a support plan? Do I raise the ticket with you?

Comment: I'm not a support engineer and I don't have direct access to the whitelisting tools. If you do not have a support plan, you may be able to get assistance via Twitter by tweeting to @AzureSupport.

Comment: Actually, a better approach may be to ask the question here on the MS Q&A site. There are people there who may be able to assist without having a support plan. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-cosmos-db.html

Comment: Hi. I created the post on the link you provided.